# Unresolved external symbol on using function from library

Tags: c++, unresolved-external

i have write small noobie library. All functions working good except templated function.

There is my code, when i use this code without library build & work success but when used with library giving unresolved external error.

Project & Library settings

-c++ language standart : latest
-multibyte charset
-no sdl
-MT static
-no optimization

```
       template<typename T>
       BOOL XMCore::XMHacking::WriteMemory(uintptr_t Address, T Value, bool 
       Check, HANDLE Process)
       {
            SIZE_T mWriten;
            if (Check && IsBadWritePtr((PFunc)Address, sizeof(T)))
                 return FALSE;
            if (Process == NULL)
                 *(T*)Address = Value;
            else
                 WriteProcessMemory(Process, (PFunc)Address, &Value, sizeof(T), &mWriten);
            if (Process != NULL && mWriten == 0)
                 return FALSE;
            return TRUE;
       }
```

Comment: Template functions need to be defined in a header file so that the code is available.

Comment: `template<typename T>
   static BOOL WriteMemory(uintptr_t Address, T Value, bool Check = false, HANDLE Process = NULL);`

i dont writed here, already defined in header file

Comment: The whole code of the function you pasted above must be in the header file.

Comment: that solved my problem thanks for information. take care

Answer (score 0):

Template functions need to be defined in your header file to link properly.